# How to set JBOSS_BASE_DIR for different WildFly instances?

Tags: linux, jboss, wildfly

### My Setup

I'm currently running 2 instances of WildFly 9.0.0.CR1 on a Linux machine.

I have install scripts that set everything up. It creates a `sim_standalone` folder in addition to the existing `standalone` folder and copies in a `sim-standalone-full.xml` file (this file offsets the port number by 100).

They are both installed as services under `/etc/init.d/wildfly` and `/etc/init.d/sim-wildfly`, with `sim-wildfly` being tweaked to use a different configuration file (it points to the `sim_standalone` folder and uses the `sim-standalone-full.xml` file instead of `standalone` and `standalone-full.xml`).

---

### My Question

The only issue I'm having now is that both `wildfly` and `sim-wildfly` are using the `JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh` file to run. This causes issues because `JBOSS_BASE_DIR` points to the `standalone` folder, causing the logs to overlap and the deployments to be read from that folder for both instances.

My current solution is to create another `standalone.sh` file and change the `JBOSS_BASE_DIR` to the `sim_standalone` folder; however, I would like to know if there is a way to set `JBOSS_BASE_DIR` in one of my existing files without having to create another `standalone.sh` file. I tried setting it in `sim-wildfly.conf` since there are many other variables in there, but that didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated!

---

**EDIT**: So my `/etc/init.d/sim-wildfly` script runs `standalone.sh`. It sets the script by setting:

```
JBOSS_SCRIPT=$JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh
```

I'm trying to set it to:

```
JBOSS_SCRIPT=$JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -Djboss.server.base.dir=$JBOSS_HOME/sim_standalone
```

...but that doesn't seem to be working. It says that `Djboss.server.base.dir=$JBOSS_HOME/sim_standalone` is not a file or directory when I run `systemctl status sim-wildfly`. I tried wrapping it in quotes as well. What am I missing?

Comment: Where did the `/etc/init.d/wildfly` scripts come from? Also consider moving to WildFly 9.0.0.Final.

Comment: We copy `wildfly-init-redhat.sh` from the WildFly install folder's `bin/init.d/` to `/etc/init.d/wildfly` and `/etc/init.d/sim-wildfly` then make the appropriate edits to `sim-wildfly`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [`jboss.server.base.dir`](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Command+line+parameters) property, e.g. by calling

```
standalone.sh -Djboss.server.base.dir=/opt/server1
```

Comment: Nevermind, It looks like when it was using the `JBOSS_SCRIPT` variable, it wasn't wrapping it in quotes which was causing issues due to the space in the variable's value. I'll accept your answer since it works without me having to create another `standalone.sh` file. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. The missing quotes did look suspicious... I'm glad this works for you now.

Comment: Given that `wildfly` and `sim-wildfly` are basically identical aside from the few configuration changes I made, do you know why it might be taking `sim-wildfly` longer to start up? Running `sudo systemctl start sim-wildfly` takes about 30 seconds to complete, while `sudo systemctl start wildfly` takes about 5-10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The linux services are configured via /etc/default/wildflyX (X to indicate there may be multiples), and executed via /etc/init.d/wildfly*

then set in the config file: /etc/default/wildflyX

```
JBOSS_OPTS="--debug 38787 -Djboss.server.base.dir=$JBOSS_HOME/standalone-internet-booking"
```

`--debug PORT` is if you are using debug ports (remember to disable in /bin/standalone.conf, or it overwrites).

Do not rename the JBOSS_MODE=standalone mode to standaloneX since the init.d script will run domain setup if its not exactly standalone.